# Отказоустойчивый сервер на примере чата

Tags: сервер, многопоточность, select, чат

Есть задача написать простой сервер чата на `Си`. Есть 2 варианта:

1) Однопоточный с `select: select` на чтение. Берём первый читабельный сокет, получаем с него сообщение и отправляем остальным. Переходим к следующему читабельному сокету. Как именно получаем и отправляем? `recv` возвращает очередную порцию сообщения и мы сразу отправляем её всем остальным. Чтобы не заблочится ставим таймаут на `recv` (таймаут на получение порции данных) и устанавливаем макс. размер сообщения. Конечно, подвиснуть мы можем - в случае "байта в час", но не навечно. В случае таймаута или превышение макс. размера сообщения - закрываем сокет нарушителя, а остальным посылаем признак обрезанного сообщения - байт 1 (байт 0 - маркер конца полного сообщения). Чтобы распараллелить посылку порции сообщения по клиентам, делаем сокеты неблокируемыми и крутим `select` на запись. Клиент может нас здесь подвесить. В худшем случае выйдем только по таймауту `TCP` на неполучение `ACK`. Распараллеливать получение сообщений не имеет смысла: в большинстве случаев они предполагаются достаточно малыми, чтобы влезть во входной буфер `TCP` сокета, так что система сама за нас здесь делает работу.

2) Поскольку в первом варианте есть возможность блокировки сервера клиентом, то появился такой вариант, отказоустойчивый, но затратный по использованию памяти. По потоку на клиента. Сообщение получается целиком в свой статический буфер каждым потоком параллельно. Потом создаём по копии для всех остальных (`malloc+memcpy`) и подсоединяем к выходным очередям всех остальных. Если какая-нибудь выходная очередь превысила 5 ожидающих сообщений, то закрываем сокет нарушителя и освобождаем ресурсы. В этом варианте никакой клиент не может заблокировать остальных (работу сервера) ни в случае приёма ни в случае передачи.

Меня интересует, насколько плох первый вариант, можно ли его улучшить? Здесь меня больше интересует не сам чат, а как построить такой сервер, который бы не мог заблочить клиент. Для меня это новая задача.

ПРАВКА: к сожалению, конкретизировать вопрос не смог, но сам нашёл решение, которое меня на данный момент удовлетворяет. Приведу его здесь, может кому полезно будет. Выбрал гибридный вариант: **однопоточный select, но для каждого клиента свой входной буфер и своя очередь сообщений, все сокеты неблокируемые** (важно для send и accept). Т.о. никакой клиент не может заблочить сервер. В основном цикле обрабатываем сокеты, готовые на чтение и на запись. Если сокет готов на чтение, то читаем очередную порцию сообщения в его входной буфер. Как только собрали сообщение целиком - создаём по копии для всех остальных и подключаем к очередям. Если сокет готов для записи - записываем в него очередную порцию из сообщения в голове очереди сообщений на отправку клиента. Потоки я не использовал - не люблю многопоточность и синхронизацию. Да и прикинул, что тогда придётся по 2 потока на клиента: поскольку нужно будет ждать 2 события: получения данных в сокет и появление сообщения в очереди на отправку. Как-то так. Прошу прощения за путанность изложения. Но надеюсь, что основную мысль передал. Всем спасибо.

Comment: В чем сложность дать ответ по каждому пункту отдельно? Начал писать ответ на телефоне, но так как много текста отложил это занятие. Добрался до компьютера, и на тебе - уже нету возможности дать ответ. И это уже не первый раз когда вполне нормальные вопросы прессуют.  Автор в явном виде перечислил  свое видение решения задачи. Голосую за открытие вопроса.

Comment: В данном виде вопрос требует очень развернутого ответа. Пожалуйста, разбейте вопрос на несколько.

Comment: @sba, в таких случаях можно и самому задать вопрос, а потом ответить на него...